# pythonで外部のコマンドを実行し、その出力に処理を加える方法

Tags: python

`cat xxx`のようなコマンドをpythonから実行して、結果を受け取りたいです。
受け取る実行結果は、

```
1  aaa  3a
2  bbb  32
3  ccc  50
4  ddd  41
5  eee  15
```

のような文字列を想定しています。
この文字列の各行をスペースでフィールドに区切り、各フィールドに処理を加え出力したいです。

- 1〜2フィールド目はそのまま出力
- 3フィールド目（30など）は１６進表現の文字列と考えて数値に変換し、以下のビット演算を行なう

  - ５ビット目(０か１)を3フィールド目に出力
  - ４ビット目(０か１)を4フィールド目に出力
  - ３～１ビット目を、１０進表現(０～７)で5フィールド目に出力

出力例:

```
1  aaa  1  1  2
2  bbb  1  0  2
3  ccc  1  0  0
4  ddd  0  0  1
5  eee  1  0  5
```

このように加工することはできますか？

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じですか．このコードでは`print`してます．文字列として保持してのちのタスクに使うかもしれませんが．

```
import subprocess

contents = subprocess.check_output('cat xxx',shell=True)
for l in contents.splitlines():
    e = l.split()
    number = int(e[2],base=16)
    print(e[0],e[1],number>>4&1,number>>3&1,number&0b111)
```

Comment: `number>>5&1, number>>4&1` だと6ビット目と5ビット目になりませんか？(ビット演算はあまりやらないので、「何ビット目」という用語に関して勘違いしているかもしれませんが)

Comment: `0x32`が`1 0 2`になるので1-based(桁が1から始まる)だとおもいました

Comment: @mjy ご指摘ありがとうございます修正しました．勘違いしてコメントしてますね

Answer (score 1):

どこまでが必須な前提なのか分かりませんが、以下のように考えることをお勧めします。

- `cat xxx` をPythonから実行する -> Pythonでファイルxxxを開いて読み込む

Answer (score 0):

＠Takayuki SHIMIZUKAWA さんの言うとおり、ただ`cat`の機能なら、Pythonファイルで読み込むべきです。

しかし、`cat`以外のプログラム、特に`tail -F`のような、全部の出力すぐに出てこない場合、`iter`を使うと良いと思います。

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['cat', xxx], stdout=PIPE)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    process_content(line) # process_content の実装方法は @takoika さんの回答にご参考
```